# Get position of searched word by lucene

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I wnat to get position of word in fields that lucene search in it. For example if lucene search "Hamid" in "TextContent" filed and find 5 word in it, get me the position of this 5 word to highlight in RichTextBox.
I use C# and Lucene.net for my windows application. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `Highlighter` or `FastVectorHighlighter` in contrib? If you want to implement it by yourself you can utilize their source codes

Comment: @L.B FastVectorHighlighter is for web apps. i use windows apps. If u have sample for windows apps, i thanks to u post it here. Thanks

Comment: FastVectorHighlighter is a library: you can define the opening and closing tags (i.e `\b` `\b0`) and use it in any kind of application.